# Does $\sum_{i=1}^n \sin(i)$ converge? Prove it.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n \sin(i)$ doesn't converge. But I'm having trouble proving it.

Comment: Can you show whatever work you have done?

Comment: Note that each of the intervals $[0+\pi/6,\pi-\pi/6]$, $[2\pi+\pi/6, 3\pi-\pi/6]$, $\ldots$ contains an integer; and, on each of these intervals, the value of $\sin$ is at least $1/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a summation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $a_n\rightarrow 0$. But $sin(n)$ does not go to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Surely this is slightly incomplete. I know that $\sin(x)$ has no limit as the real variable $x$ goes to infinity. But you haven't justified that the sequence $\sin(n)$ evaluated at integers $n$ doesn't happen to converge.

Comment: True. It suffies to argue, for example, that $\sin x$ and $\sin(x+1)$ can't both be close to $0$; in fact the function $\max\{|\sin x|,|\sin(x+1)|\}$ is always at least $\sin(\pi-1/2) > 0.479$. In particular the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is not Cauchy, hence can't converge to any limit, let alone $0$.

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:** If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $a_n$ tends to 0.

Show that since $\frac {\pi}{1}$ is not rational, then by the pigeonhole principle, for any $N$, there exists $n > N$ such that $| \sin n | > \frac {1}{2}$.

Comment: I am having some problem following everything. Could you may be elaborate what has irrationality of $\pi$ and pigeonhole principle anything to do here?

Comment: @Freddy Show that there always exists some large $n$ which gets arbitrarily close to $(2k+1)\pi$, for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\sum a_n$ converges, $\lim a_n=0$.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is what Calvin, Vahid and user57101 have suggested. However, you can compute $a_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k)$ and see for yourself how the sequence behaves for large $n$.
\begin{align}
2\sin(1/2) a_n & = 2\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k) \sin(1/2) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\cos(k-1/2)-\cos(k+1/2) \right)\\
& = (\cos(1/2) - \cos(3/2)) + (\cos(3/2) - \cos(5/2)) + \cdots\\
& + (\cos(n-3/2) - \cos(n-1/2)) + (\cos(n-1/2) - \cos(n+1/2))\\
& = \cos(1/2) - \cos(n+1/2)
\end{align}
Hence,
$$a_n = \dfrac{\cos(1/2) - \cos(n+1/2)}{2 \sin(1/2)} = \dfrac12 \cot(1/2) - \dfrac{\cos(n+1/2)}{2 \sin(1/2)}$$ which oscillates about $\dfrac12 \cot(1/2)$ as $n \to \infty$ and hence it doesn't converge. However, if you want to assign a regularized value to the series, then you can assign it a value $\dfrac12 \cot(1/2)$.